# Can I use Clang libs out of source?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, clang, llvm

I have been trying to use the clang libraries out of source for some time now. Essentially I have been messing around with all sorts of cmake files. I accomplished something similar to this with llvm passes, I was able to use llvm libs out of source to compile the cpp files in the following way:

This is the cmake file in the parent directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
message(STATUS ${LLVM_VERSION})
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)

add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(myPasses)
```

The cmake file in the sub directory is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
add_llvm_library(LLVMtest MODULE
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
    file3.cpp
)
```

It would be wonderful if I could just make cmake files like this to use clang for writing FrontEndActions.

Comment: Is there a question here? It sounds as if you've managed everything. You have the source code, noone can take it away from you, and AFAICT you've even persuaded cmake to do your bidding (congratulations!) so what's the question?

Comment: The cmake I give is for an llvm pass not a clang ast visitor,the reason for putting it up there was to give an idea as to what I was looking for, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the Clang's CMake module the same way as you do with LLVM:

```
find_package(Clang REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

Then you can use Clang libraries as you would normally do with CMake projects, e.g.:

```
add_executable(ClangTest
    file1.cpp
    file2.cpp
    file3.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(ClangTest clangBasic clangEdit)
```

There are also functions similar to the ones you get from LLVM's CMake: [source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/cmake/modules/AddClang.cmake) (I haven't used them, so cannot comment on this part).